# How To Use Timer With Loop in Python

Tags: python, loops, python-3.x, timer, serial-port

I want to listen serial port and save it for every 15 seconds.
But I can't use time in loop.

It gives an error as below.

> File "serial-reader.py", line 13
>       timer.start()
>           ^ IndentationError: expected an indented block

How can I solve this problem?

```
    import threading
from contextlib import closing
import serial
counter = 0
continue_looping = True
def stopper():
    global continue_looping
    continue_looping = False

timer = threading.Timer(15, stopper)

while (counter < 9 ):
timer.start()
with open("/Users/macproretina/Desktop/data.txt", 'w') as out_file:
    with closing(serial.Serial('/dev/tty.usbmodem1411', 9600, timeout=1)) as ser:
        while continue_looping:
            line = ser.readline()   # read a '\n' terminated line
            out_file.write(line.decode('utf-8'))
            out_file.flush()
            counter = counter +1
```

Comment: just indent your code correctly and consistently. is this a copy-paste? there no such thing as `true` in python.

Comment: forget about it. when I use while(counter < 100 ), it gives same error.

Comment: You did not the line after `while`. at least as it appears here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while True:       # True must be upper-case!
    timer.start() # This is inside a loop so must be indented!
    ...
```

You'll note the error message you received tells you exactly that it needs to be indented.

Comment: Use tab or spacebar or whatever you used at the start of line 7: "global continue_looping"

Comment: Thank you!

But now it gives different error.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "serial-reader.py", line 12, in <module>
    timer.start()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/threading.py", line 582, in start
    raise RuntimeError("threads can only be started once")
RuntimeError: threads can only be started once

Comment: The error message explains your problem again. You have one timer and you try and start it in every iteration of the while loop. If you put it before the while loop and just start it once, you will not have that error.

Answer (score 0):

```
import threading
from contextlib import closing
import serial
counter = 0
continue_looping = True
def stopper():
    global continue_looping
    continue_looping = False

timer = threading.Timer(15, stopper)

while (counter < 9 ):
timer.start()
with open("/Users/macproretina/Desktop/data.txt", 'w') as out_file:
with closing(serial.Serial('/dev/tty.usbmodem1411', 9600, timeout=1)) as ser:
    while continue_looping:
        line = ser.readline()   # read a '\n' terminated line
        out_file.write(line.decode('utf-8'))
        out_file.flush()
        counter = counter +1
```

"while (counter < 9 ):
timer.start()"

just put a tab in fornd of "timer.start()" i think that should help